# Android Studio Flutter Project Dart version confilic with flutter_localizations dependence error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

My project working find in windows but when i shift it to mac import from git,
its showing the dartx version confliction with flutter_localizations here is error i am facing in android studio

```
    Because dartx >=0.2.0 <0.4.0 depends on path >=1.6.4 <1.7.0 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on path 1.7.0, dartx >=0.2.0 <0.4.0 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because saray depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and dartx ^0.2.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because saray depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and dartx ^0.2.0, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this would help:
run `flutter pub upgrade` and update dependencies to their latest version.

Comment: did you update your projects dependencies to their latest version?